# Android Widget Upgrade app.. remove the widget

Tags: android, widget

Steps:

Download my app 3.0 from market.
add the widget of my app.
now sign the of my app 4.0.
install the latest 4.0 app on the device.

it remove the widget on some devices. user have to explicitly add the widget again. i want to udpate the existing widget.

any idea ??

Answer (score 2):

Which devices are you talking about? You must not change the WidgetProviders class name and the BroadcastReceiver and your package name (obviously) to allow updates of widgets. I never heard that updating a package makes you loose your widget if you pay attention to the things above.

Comment: its working fine on samsung galaxy s3, LG optimus 2.2, Galaxy note.. and its not working on HTC EVO, Samsung Galaxy S etc. My class name is same (which extends the AppWidgetProvider) and the reciver code (in androidmenifest) also same.

Comment: Actually we only changed the UI of the widget and added 2 new components.
Why its accepted on few device and why not on others ??

layout->xml->wordwidget.xml
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:resizeMode="none"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="5400000" 
    android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen" />